# POST request to download the image in the Vkontakte on python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, vk

How to upload photos on the server? I know I need to convert the image into byte array, and then make a post request to the server. 
The request must be the URL from the method `photos.getWallUploadServer()` and the image itself.

Response to the POST request :

```
{"server":622829,"photo":"[]","hash":"daafd680b6ff3333da31cc3094872d60"}
```

Converting images into bytecode:

```
with open('1.png', 'rb') as imageFile:
    f=imageFile.read()
    b=bytearray(f)
```

the POST request:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url=Object['upload_url'], data=b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use method `photos.getWallUploadServer` to get a link to upload. You must send account access_token in request to this method. Then you parsing an url from response, replacing "\" to the empty.
After that you making a POST-request with one field which name is "photo" and putting a image converted to bytes into the request`s body.
Server will give you all hashes, server numbers and others also with param "photos". You parse all it and send to`photos.saveWallPhoto`. 
Real servers answer format differs from API documentation so you should check it and fix parsing rules